# I want to apply for Schengen visa, but employer NOC which is mandatory document for visa is not available with me

Tags: schengen, india, schengen-visas

I have resigned from my current company and will be joining a new company soon.

Hence, I cannot get a leave approval letter from my current company, and if I decide to join a new company and then request a NOC (No Objection Certificate) it will be late for visa process completion because of my traveling dates.

What can I show to the embassy as an alternative to this NOC document?

Comment: Could you confirm that your intended travel dates are after you will leave your current job? Are you still searching for your next job, or have you already accepted an offer?

Comment: Your first question needs to be - how do you know your new company will give you the time off to make this trip? Have you asked them? If you have then maybe you can ask the new new company to give you an NOC even before you start with them?

Comment: @ChrisH I have mentioned in my Cover letter about my travel dates which are after leaving my current job. And yes i have accepted the offer letter.

Comment: @DJClayworth I had word with my new company they are okay with my travel plan but cannot issue any formal letter because i have not joined them yet and my details are not present on company's portal.

Comment: @mangeshshelar in those circumstances, I doubt there's any alternative document you can provide instead. I can only suggest you contact your new company again, explain the situation and ask what they need from you in order to issue such a letter. Even if your details aren't in their system yet, that shouldn't mean they're *unable* to write a letter confirming that you will be employed there from <your contract's start date> and that they have approved your vacation plans.

Comment: Did you finally get the visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming it is a short term single entry tourist visa. Given the circumstances, I suggest you provide new offer letter with date of joining highlighted along with relieving letter from old company with date of last working date.

**Though this does not work as a replacement for NOC**, the documents tells that you are not intending to move as an immigrant. Please note that the country to which you are applying and your travel plan also matters. If the country you are visiting is well known for tourism and your stay arrangements are within the tourist places, your application might be considered.

I have a friend who changed 3 jobs and travelled to three countries (including 1 within schengen area) in between her jobs. So I know they will not turn down your application outright because you don't have an NOC.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment.  I am staying in Munich  in same hotel for all 10 days of my vacation. I have prepared detailed Itinerary for each day with what places i am visiting. I hope they will consider this positively.

Comment: Please add in your cover letter as well, that you are enclosing the offer letter from new company with date of joining highlighted. You can find sample cover letters here - https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/application-cover-letter/

Comment: Great!! But I don't understand why the downvote. Is it because of the lack of documented clause saying it is not mandatory?

Comment: Indeed, unexplained downvotes are irksome.  This one is especially so, because this is a great answer.